# delete/flush X$KRBMSFT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Does anyone know if it is possible to delete data from or flush X$KRBMSFT table?

I am using it to collect a list of the files from a OS folder but after I delete the files, they are still displayed in X$KRBMSFT table.

I was expected to be overwritten with actual filenames (in this case, to display nothing).

I used a regular deletion command but it displayed error

> ORA-02030: can only select from fixed tables/views

Answer (score 0):

Execute `dbms_backup_restore.searchfiles()` again after you delete the files to refresh the list in memory.